# Wondering about workout "rythm"

Tags: workout

I'm very sorry for the title, please help me correct it, can't figure a better one!

I've been practicing this [shoulder workout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voVahaOGp-4) of Mike Chang, and getting some positive results

I wonder can i apply this "rythm" for other workout, i mean in the above link, the workout follows this order : 12 reps - 8 reps - 6 reps - 4 reps - 2 reps , 10 seconds rest between,  while i normally follow this order : 4 rounds, 12 reps each round, 1 minute rest between

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is a classic pyramid style rep scheme.  The fact that Chang is using minimal rest times is what's a little different.

- Classic pyramid rep scheme usually goes up in weight each set, but rest times are longer.
- Chang's pyramid rep scheme uses *fatigue* for the increased challenge.
- Combines training and conditioning into the workout.

Can you apply the approach to other exercises?  Absolutely.  You may have to adjust the between set time based on how much time it takes to get into position, but it's not a bad way to train.

Just understand that no training style will work forever.  When you stop getting results change to a different approach.  When that stops working you might be able to come back to this and start seeing results again.